# Using quotes and apostrophes in php form

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form that uploads data to a mysql database. There is an external php file that processes the form. I am having an issue when someone uses a quote or an apostrophe. Here is an example of what is entered into the form and what appears in the database:

If I enter `target's` in the form, it comes out `target\&#39;s` in the database
If I enter `"Sud"` in the form, it comes out `\"Sud\"` in the database

In the variable declaration, I am using this:

```
$var = mysql_escape_string($_POST['var']);
```

and in the insert statement, I am using this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO tablename VALUES ('$var')";
```

I also tried `mysql_real_escape_string` and when I used that function, no data was inserted at all into the table.

Can someone please tell me what I need to do to escape those characters so the data comes out just as entered in the form? Thank you.

Comment: Dont use mysql_* functions anymore, they are depraced as of PHP5.5.0. Use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) for this.

Answer (score 0):

First, please note that mysql_escape_string is deprecated, see [mysql_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-escape-string.php)

Second, i suspect your issue is caused by the table character set, try using mysql_real_escape_string to see if this fixes it.

Please note that mysql_real_escape_string is also deprecated

Comment: Lamine. Thanks for your response. I'm not sure I understand. You said try using mysql_real_escape_string but then you say it is also deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

It's safer, and *easier*, to use PDO and query parameters:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO tablename (columnname) VALUES (?)";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute([$_POST['var']]);
```

With query parameters, you never need to worry about quoting/escaping, or possible apostrophes or any other tricky characters.

Query parameters are also supported by the mysqli extension, but I recommend you skip over mysqli and learn PDO. PDO is easier to use.